# Cocoa Typography: wrong presentation of space unicode characters

Tags: cocoa

It seems that something wrong with typography system in Cocoa.

When i try to draw string over the screen with drawInRect (Helvetica):

```
NSString *tot = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MMM%CMMM%CMMM MMM", 0x2002, 0x20];
```

all spaces between letters are the same. But first unicode character is En Space - Width of one en (half of one em).

Same spaces with other characters, like Four-Per-Em Space Mid Space and so on.

Comment: @Seth - randomly trying fonts isn't the answer. Helvetica Neue doesn't have these particular glyphs either.

Comment: @fake it's not random. Neue has more faces than standard Helvetica; it stood to reason that it might have more glyphs too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even tho the glyph you want to draw ('En Space U+2002') is "just a space", it still has to be available in the font you are using.

You will need a much better font than the operating system bundled Helvetica if you want En Space, Four-Per-Em Space, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know maybe any tool to check glyph and their presentation in Mac OS X ?

Comment: Open the Finder's 'Special Characters…' window (Edit > Special Characters…). At the top of the window change 'View' to 'Code Tables' and at the bottom of the window change 'Font Variation > Collections :' to 'Containing selected character'. You should the be able to browse which fonts have which code points.

Comment: @blackliteon - I notice that some fonts contain an En Space or an Em Space but that they are not what you would expect. While this is bad, it is because the font was designed that way (for some reason) and not the fault of the Coco rendering.